# Wordpress Table Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to find a plugin that will allow me to input information by category and then display on a page a table by category. For example:

I would have the following data:

**String**   **Category**
Text 1      Category 1
Text 2      Category 1
Text 3      Category 2
Text 4      Category 3
Text 5      Category 3

But then I want to display this information in a table by category on a webpage. One page may include a table that only displays Category 1. Another page may have a table that displays information from Categories 1, and 2. And so on.

There are many table plugins out there, I am just having a hard time finding something that would allow me to do this.

I guess what I am trying to avoid, is having to create multiple tables for the same type of data (but may be slightly different for each one). I would like to have one central list and then assign it categories and have it display tables based on the categories I want it to display. And by the way it does not have to be a free plugin.

Comment: Are you trying to just add the ability to add tables to the Page's content editor? Or when you say Category 1, are you referring to blog post categories, and a table built on-the-fly based on data?